# Retrieve an item from a DynamoDB table that has a range key by only specifying the index key

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with a primary key and range key set:

```
user_id
timestamp_joined
```

Using the boto api layer, is there a way I can retrieve the item just by specifying the user_id (without the range key)? Every time I perform a getItem() query without specifying the range key it fails. I can only get it to work by specifying the range key (timestamp_joined).

The error message when fetching just by user_id is below:

```
boto.exception.DynamoDBResponseError: DynamoDBResponseError: 400 Bad Request 
{'message': 'One or more parameter values were invalid: The provided 
key size does ot match with that of the schema', '__type':
'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'}
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to perform a query.  You can query the table specifying only the user_id (the hash key) and the query will return all items that match that user_id regardless of the range value.

Comment: In this table, for example, user_id is unique. Do I still have to run query() even though I'm only looking for one result? It's not possible to use getItem() only on the hash key? It sounds like maybe a range_key shouldn't be specified on this table.

Comment: The only way to do a get_item without specifying a range key is if the schema of the table doesn't include a range key.  So, if the timestamp isn't useful as a secondary key, I wouldn't include it in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = table.scan(Attr('user_id').eq(/number here/),
                    Limit=1,
                    ConsistentRead=True)
```

If you have more than 1 item per user_id you can limit the results by a greater number up to 1M of results per scan or query.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in date range

I have my table with dates:
[image]

And I made a query like this:

```
import requests, json 
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1', aws_access_key_id='your_access',aws_secret_access_key='your_secret')
    table = dynamodb.Table('Table_name')

    date_i = '2013-11-18'
    date_f = '2013-11-19'

    try:
        fe = Key('Date').between(date_i,date_f);
        response = table.scan(
            FilterExpression=fe
        )
        print(response['Items'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

I had 2 results with that range.